# Why do Catholics venerate Our Lady?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, virgin-mary, veneration

This is a simple question. Why do Catholics venerate and pray to Our Lady?
God says not to do it.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a mini rant, an argument, or a question.  By "God says not to do it" what do you mean?  how do you know?  Please add some sources and details to your question so that what you mean by that is clear.  Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see a few ways that this site is different from a discussion forum.

Comment: Welcome!  Please review the links I've added above your question, and also note that on each one, in the right sidebar, other similar questions will appear under the "Related" header.  Please check and see if any of them answer your question, and if not, please clarify this question to make it clear how other questions fail to ask what you are asking.  Thanks!